# How do I send formdata plus some additional parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been able to send formdata succesfully using jquery ajax using this code:

```
        const file = $("#proof-of-payment")[0].files[0];
        if (file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", file);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/payments/documents",
                method: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            })
            .done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
                if (textStatus === "success") {
                    alert('a');
                }
            })
            .fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });
        }
```

My Web API controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost("documents")]
    public void Save(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Now I want to pass in some additional data. I tried doing this:

```
        const file = $("#proof-of-payment")[0].files[0];
        if (file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", file);
            formData.append("notes", $("#notes_hidden").val());

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/payments/documents",
                method: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            })
            .done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
                if (textStatus === "success") {
                    alert('a');
                }
            })
            .fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });
        }
```

And in controller:

```
    [HttpPost("documents")]
    public void Save(DocumentDto files)
    {
    }

    public class DocumentDto
    {
        public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile>();
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

But I get an error of unsupported media type. Whats is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Could you share your View and the version of asp.net core?I could not reproduce error of unsupported media type but could pass only one file to the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working demo like below:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="proof-of-payment" name="payment" multiple/>
    <input type="text" id="notes_hidden" />
    <input type="button" onclick="Test()" value="click" />
</form>
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
      function Test() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            $("input[name='payment']").each(function () {
                var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
                if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                    $.each(ReadyToUpload, function (i, file) {
                        formData.append("Files", file);
                    });
                }
            });
            formData.append("Notes", $("#notes_hidden").val());
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/documents",
                method: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            })
                .done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
                    if (textStatus === "success") {
                        alert('a');
                    }
                })
                .fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                });     
    }

  </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]